# Functor $R^2 \otimes -$ for a ring $R$ is left-exact?

Tags: category-theory, tensor-products, exact-sequence

If $R$ is a ring, is there a simple way of showing that the functor $R^2 \otimes -$ from the category of $R$-modules to the one of abelian groups is left-exact?

I know it is right-exact, I have a suspicion it should also be left exact. Now I know it is not true if we simply replace $R^2$ by $R$ and I think the way I am proceeding would prove that wrong result too... So I know I'm not doing this the right way and I still don't know why...

Now I think I manage to break the proof down to showing that for an $R$-module $N$, $R^2 \otimes N$ is the same as the direct sum of two copies of $N$. I still don't see how to manage that...

I am a bit lost with category theory so any help would be very much appreciated!

Comment: Use that $R \otimes_R N \cong N$ via $r \otimes n \mapsto rn$, and that $(M_1 \oplus M_2) \otimes_R N \cong (M_1 \otimes_R N) \oplus (M_2 \otimes_R N)$ via $(m_1, m_2) \otimes r \mapsto (m_1 \otimes r, m_2 \otimes r)$.

Comment: Did you mean $\otimes$($\otimes_{\Bbb Z}$) or $\otimes_R$?

Comment: We view $R^2$ as an $R$-module here so the second